# sumifs formula in vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to populate a column with a SUMIFS formula if the criteria is matched.

```
cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "=SUMIFS(PickData!E:E,PickData!A:A, _
" & cell.Address(Rowabsolute:=False, Column:=False) & ", PickData!C:C, _
 "Retail",PickData!C:C, PickData!L:L, "Report1.TextBox1.Value")"
```

I can't see where i'm going wrong with it looking up the specific work Retail in PickData|C:C & the value from TextBox1 (this is date)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Al

Comment: Do you want to set a value to the cell or put a formula into the cell. You currently have half of one and half of the other. Perhaps all you need to change is `cell.Offset(0, 2).Formula =`

Comment: You are also not referring to the ColumnAbsolute argument in the .Address function:    Rowabsolute:=False, Column:=False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a formula in the cell(s) then try this.

```
cell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=SUMIFS(PickData!E:E, PickData!A:A, " _
    & cell.Address(0, 0) & ", PickData!C:C, " & Chr(34) & "Retail" & Chr(34) _
    & ", PickData!L:L, DATEVALUE(" & Report1.TextBox1.Value & "))"
```

That should give you a valid SUMIFS(...) formula.

Addendum: looking at that a second time, the form's textbox value might need to be in quotes.

```
cell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=SUMIFS(PickData!E:E, PickData!A:A, " _
    & cell.Address(0, 0) & ", PickData!C:C, " & Chr(34) & "Retail" & Chr(34) _
    & ", PickData!L:L, DATEVALUE(" & Chr(34) & Report1.TextBox1.Value & Chr(34) & "))"
```

Comment: @Alan Treanor - Glad you got sorted out. BTW, if you preface the formula string with a tick it will be written into the cell(s) as a text string and you can often see where a mistake has been made. e.g. `cell.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "'=SUMIFS(...`. You can see what went wrong with the formula creation using this method (assuming  that you got the quotes within a quoted string reasonably correct). Removing the tick after it is corrected is a small matter.